# ADO stream concert to binary

Tags: excel, vba

This is the code that I use to upload file into database using VBA, but this loop can only run once. During the second loop it will give error, the error is

> Operation is  not allowed in this context

Can anybody suggest me what to do? 
The error is in the line `adoStream.Type = adTypeBinary`

```
Dim stCon As String 'SQL Connection string
Dim stProcName As String 'Stored Procedure name

Dim strCmd As String

Dim adoStream               As Object
Dim adocmd                  As Object
Dim strFilePath             As String
Dim adoCon                  As Object

Set adoCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set adoStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
Set adocmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

adoCon.CursorLocation = adUseClient
adoCon.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB; " & _
            "Data Source=#########; " & _
            "Initial Catalog=#######;" & _
            "User ID=#######; Password=########;"

For Each fl In fld.Files    
    If fl.name Like Mask Then
        strInput = fl.name
        strFilePath = fld.path & "\" & fl.name

        MsgBox (strFilePath)

        adoStream.Type = adTypeBinary
        adoStream.Open
        adoStream.LoadFromFile strFilePath 'It fails if file is open

        With adocmd 
            .CommandText = "INSERT INTO dbo.coc_upload(Data) " & _
                           "VALUES (?)"
            .CommandType = adCmdText
            '---adding parameters
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Data", adVarBinary, adParamInput, adoStream.Size, adoStream.Read)
            '---
        End With

        adocmd.ActiveConnection = adoCon
        adocmd.Execute
        adoCon.Close

        MsgBox ("Done")    
    End If      
Next
```

Comment: I suspect the error is actually happening on the next line. You haven't closed the adoStream.

Comment: When I close the adoStream it gives error, **Operation is not allowed when the object is close**

Comment: Hmmm - ok was hoping that would help...have you tried moving the open statement above the loop?

Comment: I finally can get the code run, just have to modfiy this

Comment: Have to declare this code inside the loop

Comment: Set adoCon = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
      Set adoStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
      Set adocmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    
 
      adoCon.CursorLocation = adUseClient
      adoCon.Open "Provider=#######; " & _
                "Data Source=########; " & _
                "Initial Catalog=BFT;" & _
                "User ID=#### Password=#####;"

Comment: Anyway thanks @Jon Vote for replying to this thread

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it to work.

Comment: @syah - Feel free to post an answer to your own question since you've found the problem.  It's [okay](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to do that on SO.

Comment: When you show the code, please, make yourself show *all* the code. What are `fl` and `fld` variables?

Comment: @JohnyL , the fl is the files,  the fld  is the folder, hence fld.Files indicate the folder in the files